# Module "django.template.context_processors" does not define a "custom_proc" attribute/class

Tags: python, django, requestcontext

```
def custom_proc(request):
"A context processor that provides 'app', 'user' and 'ip_address'."
return {
    'app': 'My app',
    'user': request.user,
    'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
}
```

above code is my code. a request Context. i write this code in a file context_processors.py.
and follow code is in settings.py file:
`'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.custom_proc',`
how to use the context processor in the view.py file?

````
        return render(request,'template1.html',
        {'message': 'I am view 1.'})```
    enter code here
````

Answer (score 0):

The path `'django.template.context_processors.custom_proc'` to your context processor is not correct.

If you have created the file `context_processors.py` in an app directory called `my_app`, then your `settings.py` should have something like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'my_app.context_processors.custom_proc',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```